# How to import & use @Google/maps npm package in Nuxt?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, server, client, nuxt.js

I have an npm package, `@Google/maps` which I'd like to use as part of my app. But unfortunately, that package is used on a node server.

But I have a spa Nuxt app without a server, so how can I still use this? Also, I don't want to resort to other vue npm packages.

This is what I have so far:

`~/plugins/server-only.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'

const GoogleClient = require('@google/maps')

Vue.use(GoogleClient)
```

`~/components/organisms/helloWorld.vue`

```js
// ... Vue template

// Vue Js
export default {

  mounted() {
  
    console.log(this.$GoogleClient); // undefined

  }

}
```

I guess what boils down to is this. How can I export the Google Map so that I can import it in my client vue component?

Thanks

Comment: See solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073998/how-to-use-google-map-api-in-nuxt-js/73495157#73495157

Answer (score 0):

In your nuxt.config file, try to add this

```
plugins: [
    {src: '~/plugins/server-only.js', ssr: false},
  ],
```

Then, call the component in your .vue file inside a `<client-only>` tag.

I guess this will solve your problem.

Comment: Why would I make ssr false for something that needs outside client? Also I can't inside `client-only`, as I need to be calling `createClient()` method on mounted.