# How to use Google Map API in Nuxt Js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

This is my code below to fetch API in Nuxt.Js. I have written the code that should be used to call an API, but I am not getting the results. I am not getting any resources regarding this as well.

```js
async created(){
  const config = {
    headers : {
      Accept : "application/json"
    }
  };
  try{
    const result = await axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap`, config);
    console.warn(result);
    //this.users = result.data;
  }
  catch (err){
    console.warn(err);
  }
},
```

Comment: What if you try this on a button click?

Comment: @kissu, Plz elaborate

Comment: Actually, you should be the one to elaborate. What did you tried so far? Do you something in the network tab? Since there is not enough code here to see if it's a lifecycle issue, I do recommend running the `axios.get` via a `@click` event. Try this and give us some more details please.

Comment: Can you send me a working code sample if you have one? I need it urgently.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a coding service. I cannot send you a sample for something that need to code yourself. I can meanwhile, help you debug your code **issues**. Of course, for that I need to understand what is your actual issue. If you want it to be fixed quickly, please focus on providing what I've asked for in my previous comment and we will try our best to solve it together.

Comment: If you don't mind can I send you the whole source code, so that you can look into it?

Comment: Please edit your question with the **relevant** source that will help us find out what is your issue. Also, please answer to my first comment if you want this to be fixed quickly.

Comment: I have used axios.get but still not getting the result in the console.

Comment: Alright, now please answer the rest of my first comment.

Comment: @kissu, Thanks I got the solution. Thanks for answering my queries.

Comment: Hi, what is the solution? Feel free to post your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

### **Use the official GM NPM loader + diy Nuxt plugin**

There's an official npm loader for the Google Maps JS API:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview#Loading_the_Maps_API

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader

Below is how I have it implemented in Nuxt (2.15.7).

**Side note:** Yes, this places your API key client side, which in some contexts (e.g. internal team tools) is fine. For public production deployment, you probably want to protect the API key behind a proxy server, and keep any communication with Google occurring only on your server. A proxy server works great for things like Google search and geolocation services, however for map tiles you may never have a map tile server as fast as Google, so you may have to keep an API key on client-side to ensure smooth performance.

### **1. Install**

`npm i @googlemaps/js-api-loader`

### **2. Make your own Nuxt plugin**

`plugins/mapGoogle.client.js`

This keeps the Google Map API as a global so you can make use of it in various components (i.e. non-map contexts, like searching Google Places in a form).

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader'

// Store GM_instance as a window object (outside of the Vue context) to satisfy the GM plugin.
window.GM_instance = new Loader({
    apiKey: process.env.GOOGLEMAPSAPIKEY, // This must be set in nuxt.config.js
    version: "weekly",
    libraries: ["places", "drawing", "geometry"] // Optional GM libraries to load
})

Vue.mixin({

    data() {
        return {
            GM_loaded: false, // Tracks whether already GM loaded
            GM_instance: null // Holds the GM instance in the context of Vue; much more convenient to use *anywhere* (Vue templates or scripts) whereas directly accessing the window object within Vue can be problematic.
            GM_placeService: null, // Optional - Holds the GM Places service
        }
    },

    methods: {

        GM_load() {
            return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {

                // Need to do this only once
                if (!this.GM_loaded) {

                    // Load the GM instance
                    window.GM_instance.load()
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.GM_loaded = true
                        
                        // this.GM_instance is what we use to interact with GM throughout the Nuxt app
                        this.GM_instance = response

                        resolve()
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        reject(e)
                    })
                } else {
                    resolve()
                }
            })
        },

        // OPTIONAL FUNCTIONS:


        GM_loadPlaceService(map) {
            this.GM_placeService = new this.GM_instance.maps.places.PlacesService(map)
        },

        GM_getPlaceDetails(placeRequest) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                this.GM_placeService.getDetails(placeRequest, (response) => {
                    resolve(response)
                })
            })
        }
    }
})
```

### **3. Set env and plugin in nuxt config**

`nuxt.config.js`

Pass your GM key from your .env file and register your new plugin.

```
export default {
    // ...

    // It's best to keep your GM key where all other keys are: your .env file; however this is inaccessible client-side.
    // Here, we tell Nuxt the specific env's we want to make available client-side.
    env: {
        GOOGLEMAPSAPIKEY: process.env.GOOGLEMAPSAPIKEY
    },

    // Register your new plugin
    plugins: [
        '@/plugins/mapGoogle.client.js',
    ],

    // ...
}
```

### **4. Now use the GM plugin anywhere**

`components/map.vue`

Make a map and process clicks on Google Places

```
<template>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "MapGoogle",

    data() {
        return {
            map: null
        }
    },

    mounted() {

        // This is the actual trigger that loads GM dynamically.
        // Here we run our global GM func: GM_load.
        // Side note; annoyance: As you see, using Vue mixin's, you have functions available from out-of-nowhere. Research alternative to mixin's, especially in Vue3/Nuxt3.
        this.GM_load()
        .then( () => {
            this.initMap()
        })

    },


    methods: {

        initMap() {

            this.map = new this.GM_instance.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: { lat: 43.682284, lng: -79.401603 },
                zoom: 8,
            })

            this.GM_loadPlaceService(this.map)

            this.map.addListener("click", (e) => {
                this.processClick(e)
            })

        }
    },

    async processClick(e) {
      
        // If clicked target has a placeId, user has clicked a GM place
        if (e.placeId) {
         
            let placeRequest = {
                placeId: e.placeId,
                //fields: ['name', 'rating', 'formatted_phone_number', 'geometry']
            }

            // Get place details
            let googlePlace = await this.GM_getPlaceDetails(placeRequest)
            console.log("googlePlace %O", googlePlace)
        }
            
    }
}
</script>
```